# Validator works for all fields except one in flutter

Tags: flutter, validation

I have a screen to add a customer's details. Name, company, mobile no.,email,profile picture. I have added validator to all the fields. Validator is working for all the fields but not for one field, the top one(Name). I dont know why. When I place the field below all the fields then the validator works but I want to keep the field on top. I want Name field to contain some value.

add_person.dart

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:email_validator/email_validator.dart';
import 'package:vers2cts/models/customer_model.dart';
import 'package:vers2cts/models/language.dart';
import 'package:vers2cts/models/languages_widget.dart';
import 'package:vers2cts/models/languages_model.dart';
import 'package:vers2cts/screens/people_list.dart';
import 'package:vers2cts/services/db_service.dart';

import 'package:vers2cts/utils/form_helper.dart';
import 'search_contacts.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class AddPerson extends StatefulWidget {
  String uname;
  final String appBarTitle;
  final CustomerModel customer;

  AddPerson(this.uname,this.customer,this.appBarTitle);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return AddPersonState(uname,customer,appBarTitle);
  }
}


class AddPersonState extends State<AddPerson> {

  GlobalKey<FormState> globalFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String uname,email,mobnum;
  AddPersonState(this.uname,this.customer,this.appBarTitle);
 

  bool engcheckbox=false;
  String appBarTitle;
  CustomerModel customer=new CustomerModel();
  LanguagesModel langs=new LanguagesModel();

  DBService dbService=new DBService();
  bool showPassword = false;
  DateTime _date=DateTime.now();
  TextEditingController datefield=TextEditingController();

  PickedFile _imageFile;
  final ImagePicker _picker=ImagePicker();

  TextEditingController custfNameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController custlNameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController custMobileNoController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController custCompanyController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController addrController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController custEmailController = TextEditingController();


  void getImage(ImageSource source) async{
    final pickedFile=await _picker.getImage(
        source:source);
    setState(() {
      _imageFile=pickedFile;
      customer.cust_photo = _imageFile.path;

    });
  }

  Future<Null> _selectDate(BuildContext context)async {
    DateTime _datePicker = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: _date,
      firstDate: DateTime(1947),
      lastDate: DateTime(2030),);
    if (_datePicker != null && _datePicker != _date) {
      setState(() {
        _date = _datePicker;

        String formattedDate = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(_date);
        datefield.text=formattedDate.toString();
        print(datefield.text);
      
      });
    }
  }
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    var selectedLanguages = languages.where((element) => element.selected);
    TextStyle textStyle=Theme.of(context).textTheme.title;
    var height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    var _minimumPadding = 5.0;
    custfNameController.text = customer.first_name;
    custlNameController.text = customer.last_name;
    custMobileNoController.text = customer.mob_num;
    custCompanyController.text=customer.org_name;
    addrController.text=customer.addr;
    custEmailController.text=customer.email_id;

    return WillPopScope(

        onWillPop: () {
          moveToLastScreen();
        },

        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(appBarTitle),
         
            elevation: 1,
            actions: [
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.search,

                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => SearchContacts()));
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
          body:Form(
                 key: globalFormKey,
                child: Container(

            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, top: 25, right: 16),
            child:
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
              },
              child: ListView(
                children: [
                  ImageProfile(customer.cust_photo),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 35,
                  ),


                  buildTextField("Name",custfNameController,
                          (value) => updatefName(value),(value)=>checkfname(value)),
                 buildTextField("Mobile",custMobileNoController,
                          (value) => updateMobile(value),(value)=>checkmobile(value)),
                  buildTextField("Company",custCompanyController,
                          (value) => updateCompany(value),(value)=>checkempty(value)),
                  buildTextField("Email",custEmailController,
                          (value) => updateEmail(value),(value)=>checkmail(value)),

                  Text("Address"),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: addrController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(width: 2.0),)),
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                      minLines: 5,//Normal textInputField will be displayed
                      maxLines: 5, // when user presses enter it will adapt to it
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        this.customer.addr = value;
                      },

                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: height * 0.02,
                  ),
                 
                  Divider(),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: height * 0.02,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                          child: Text("Show on Call",
                            style: textStyle,
                            
                          )
                      ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: height * 0.02,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 35,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      OutlineButton(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Text("CANCEL",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14,
                                letterSpacing: 2.2,
                                color: Colors.black)),
                      ),
                      RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            _saveCustomer();
                          });


                        },
                        //color: Colors.purpleAccent,
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
                        elevation: 2,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                        child: Text(
                          "SAVE",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14,
                              letterSpacing: 2.2,
                              color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),

          ),
        )));
  }

  Widget bottomSheet(){
    return Container(
      height: 100,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width ,
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        horizontal:20,
        vertical:20,
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("Choose profile photo",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              FlatButton.icon(
                  onPressed: (){
                    getImage(ImageSource.camera);
                  },
                  icon:Icon(Icons.camera,color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,), label:Text("camera")),
              FlatButton.icon(
                  onPressed: (){
                    getImage(ImageSource.gallery);
                  },
                  icon:Icon(Icons.photo_library), label:Text("Gallery"))
            ],

          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
  //This is for 1st 3 Textfields name,mobile,company
  Widget buildTextField(String labelText,tController,Function onChanged,Function validator) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 35.0),
      child: TextFormField(
        controller:tController,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 3),
          labelText: labelText,
          labelStyle:TextStyle(),
          floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
        ),
        onChanged: (String value) {
          return onChanged(value);
        },
        validator:(String value) {
          return validator(value);
    },

    ),
    );
  }
  void moveToLastScreen() {
    Navigator.pop(context, true);
  }
  bool validateAndSave() {
    final form = globalFormKey.currentState;
    if (form.validate()) {
      form.save();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
  void _saveCustomer() async {
    if (validateAndSave()) {
      var result;
      var res;
      var mob = await dbService.checkcustMobno(mobnum,uname);
      var mail = await dbService.checkcustEmail(email,uname);
    if (mob != null) {
      FormHelper.showAlertDialog(
          context, 'Error',
          'Customer with this mobile number already exists');
    }
    else if (mail != null) {
      FormHelper.showAlertDialog(
          context, 'Error',
          'Customer with this email id already exists');
    }else {
      if (customer.cust_id != null) { // Case 1: Update operation
        result = await dbService.updateCustomer(customer);
      } else { // Case 2: Insert Operation
        result = await dbService.insertCustomer(customer);
      }

      if (result != 0) { // Success
        moveToLastScreen();
        FormHelper.showAlertDialog(
            context, 'Status', 'Customer Saved Successfully');
      } else { // Failure
        FormHelper.showAlertDialog(
            context, 'Status', 'Problem Saving Customer');
      }

      languages.forEach((lang) async {
        print("${lang.name} : ${lang.selected}");
        if (lang.selected) {
          LanguagesModel language = LanguagesModel(lang: lang.name);
          print("customer id from lang");
          print(customer.cust_id);
          await dbService.insertLanguages(language);
        }
      });
    }
    }
  }
  String updatefName(String value) {
    customer.first_name = custfNameController.text;
    customer.cre_by=uname;
    print(uname);
  }
  String updatelName(String value) {
    if(value.isEmpty)
      customer.last_name = " ";
    else
      customer.last_name = custlNameController.text;
  }
  String updateMobile(value) {
    customer.mob_num = custMobileNoController.text;
    mobnum=value;
  }
  String updateEmail(value) {
    customer.email_id = custEmailController.text;
    email=value;
  }
    String updateCompany(String value) {

      customer.org_name = custCompanyController.text;
    }
  String checkfname(String value){
    if(value.isEmpty)
    {
      return "First name can't be null";
    }
    return null;
  }

    String checkempty(String value){
      print("checkempty called");
      if(value.isEmpty)
      {
        return "Can't be null";
      }
      return null;
    }
  String checkmobile(String value) {
    print("checkmobile called");
    if(value.isEmpty)
    {
      return 'Please enter phone no.';
    }
    if(value.length<6)
    {
      return 'Please enter a valid phone no.';
    }

    return null;
    }

    String checkmail(String value){
      print("checkmail called");
      if(value.isEmpty)
      {
        return 'Please Enter E-mail address';
      }
      if (!EmailValidator.validate(value)) {
        return 'Please enter a valid Email';
      }
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `ListView` (that the `buildTextField`s are its children) with a `Column` and wrap the `Column` with a `SingleChildScrollView`.